# preg_replace find phone number and remove spaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this function to find phone numbers and replace them with a clickable link, I want to remove spaces from the phone number because the numbers order breaks when it is mixed with RTL (right to left) text:

```
$content_data = preg_replace('!(\b\+?[0-9()\[\]./ -]{7,17}\b|\b\+?[0-9()\[\]./ -]{7,17}\s+(extension|x|#|-|code|ext)\s+[0-9]{1,6})!i', '<a class="external text-ltr" href="tel:$1">$1</a>', $content_data);
```

How should I modify the code to remove spaces `' '` from the phone numbers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

EDITED:

```
$content_data = preg_replace_callback(
  '!(\b\+?[0-9()\[\]./ -]{7,17}\b|\b\+?[0-9()\[\]./ -]{7,17}\s+(extension|x|#|-|code|ext)\s+[0-9]{1,6})!i',
  function ($matches){
    $tel=str_replace(" ", "", $matches[0]);
    return '<a class="external text-ltr" href="tel:'.$tel.'">'.$tel.'</a>';
  },
  $content_data
);
```

Comment: I got: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in ......`

Comment: @tinyCoder: Yepp you are right, I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I know this is too much, but do you think you can provide a way to include the `+` sign with the phone number? right now the result is `+<a href="123456">123456</a>`, the plus sign is not included in the preg_replace pattern.

Comment: The `\b` matches after the `+` that is the reason it's left outside. Use this regexp: `'!(\+?[0-9()\[\]./ -]{7,17}\b|\+?[0-9()\[\]./ -]{7,17}\s+(extension|x|#|-|code|ext)\s+[0-9]{1,6})!i'`

Comment: Cool! it would take me my whole life to understand how to build regular expressions' patterns, thanks again dude. 